# Unity - how to remove standard sky but keep the lighting?

Tags: unity, lighting

How can I remove the standard Unity sky (to have an empty space with no texture around my scene), but keep all the lighting effects from it?

Comment: Could you not just set your camera's "clear" setting to "solid colour" instead of the default setting "skybox"? This should skip rendering the skybox into the camera's view without affecting lighting at all.

Answer (score 4):

In your scene, select your Main Camera and, in the *Inspector*, change its "*Clear Flags*" settings in the `Camera` component from "*Skybox*" to "*Solid Color*." Then choose the color you'd like:

[image]

Note: There are no "lighting effects" in the skybox, it's simply a collection of textures.  Any lighting effects should be the result of lights placed in the scene and shaders on the materials of your objects.

Comment: Doesn't the skybox affect global illumination?

Comment: @Philipp Not any more than it "affects" reflections. A skybox (in Unity) is just a mesh (either a box with six textures, or a tessellated sphere) rendered around your scene; it's not a light source.  You can have global illumination without a skybox.

Comment: The instructions in this answer are correct, but the comments on the role of the skybox may be misleading. By default, Unity does use a skybox for computing ambient light in the scene. The instructions given here don't interfere with that function though - the skybox doesn't actually need to be drawn by the scene camera to still be useful for lighting.

Answer (score 3):

(This is an old post I know but in the mere chance of someone passing through this page still)

If he was referring to "scene" as the Scene View window in Unity, not the game view. You can toggle the sky view from the scene view's menu bar. There's a simple toggle button with a drop down menu allowing you to disable the skybox entirely from the scene view.
[image: Easy Peasy]

Which is what I personally was looking for, although creating a new one is optional too.

For those who simply want a mere single click or two this option works as well.

The default skybox is such an eye sore, prefer a solid background.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom skybox.  Not much else to say.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I could elaborate somewhat possibly.